# How to detect if other element exists and adjust positioning accordingly

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following snippet:

```css
.above-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: teal;
  text-align: center;
}

.indicator {
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightpink;
  width: 175px;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.button span {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="above-content">Text in the middle</div>
<div class="indicator"></div>
<a class="button"><span>Button that should be right aligned</span></a>
```

The above shows the desired behaviour on mobile & tablet, with the indicator sitting above the button (always positioned to the right). However, on desktop I want to ensure that the indicator and the button are on the same level horizontally: with the indicator sitting in the middle of the viewport and the button positioned to the right.

I know I can achieve this to an extent by adding a `margin-top: -30px` (the height of the indicator) to the button.

But this solution only works when both the button and the indicator are present in the DOM, either or both may be excluded at any given time.

How can I update my CSS so that the button can calculate if the indicator exists and if so, move "up" accordingly?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator